# Shell script: Sed substitution throwing unknown command: ` '

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, sed

I'm having some trouble getting around an issue related to performing a sed substitution with array's being passed into it as variables. I'm nearly certain it has something to do with the way I'm passing the variables, but I've been scouring for hours for a solution to no avail.

The arrays are initialized in the first six lines of code before attempting a sed substitution. The full script is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

scalarLineNums=( $(grep -nr 'MCSTEP\|NCSTEP\|ISAVE\|DCGRAX\|DCGRAY\|DCGRAZ\|DCSTEC\|DCTIME\|ICOUTF\|ICOUTI\|D1PEKS\|D1PEFR\|D1PEPF\|MBCON\|NBCON\|D1BNVX\|D1BNVY\|D1BNVZ\|I1BNVX\|I1BNVY\|I1BNVZ\|D1BNFX\|D1BNFY\|D1BNFZ\|D1BNAX\|D1BNAY\|D1BNAZ' Layer_Rough.Y3D | cut -d ":" -f 1) )
vectorLineNums=( $(sed -n -e '/D1BNVX\|D1BNVY\|D1BNVZ\|I1BNVX\|I1BNVY\|I1BNVZ\|D1BNFX\|D1BNFY\|D1BNFZ\|D1BNAX\|D1BNAY\|D1BNAZ/{n;=;p;}' Layer_Rough.Y3D | sed -n   1~2p) )

scalarValuesOriginal=( $(grep -nr 'MCSTEP\|NCSTEP\|ISAVE\|DCGRAX\|DCGRAY\|DCGRAZ\|DCSTEC\|DCTIME\|ICOUTF\|ICOUTI\|D1PEKS\|D1PEFR\|D1PEPF\|MBCON\|NBCON\|D1BNVX\|D1BNVY\|D1BNVZ\|I1BNVX\|I1BNVY\|I1BNVZ\|D1BNFX\|D1BNFY\|D1BNFZ\|D1BNAX\|D1BNAY\|D1BNAZ' Layer_Rough.Y3D | awk -F ' +' '{print $2}') )
vectorValuesOriginal=( $(sed -n -e '/D1BNVX\|D1BNVY\|D1BNVZ\|I1BNVX\|I1BNVY\|I1BNVZ\|D1BNFX\|D1BNFY\|D1BNFZ\|D1BNAX\|D1BNAY\|D1BNAZ/{n;=;p;}' Layer_Rough.Y3D | sed -n 2~2p) )

scalarValuesNew=( $(grep -nr 'MCSTEP\|NCSTEP\|ISAVE\|DCGRAX\|DCGRAY\|DCGRAZ\|DCSTEC\|DCTIME\|ICOUTF\|ICOUTI\|D1PEKS\|D1PEFR\|D1PEPF\|MBCON\|NBCON\|D1BNVX\|D1BNVY\|D1BNVZ\|I1BNVX\|I1BNVY\|I1BNVZ\|D1BNFX\|D1BNFY\|D1BNFZ\|D1BNAX\|D1BNAY\|D1BNAZ' new-variable-list.txt | awk -F ' +' '{print $2}') )
vectorValuesNew=( $(sed -n -e '/D1BNVX\|D1BNVY\|D1BNVZ\|I1BNVX\|I1BNVY\|I1BNVZ\|D1BNFX\|D1BNFY\|D1BNFZ\|D1BNAX\|D1BNAY\|D1BNAZ/{n;=;p;}' new-variable-list.txt | sed -n 2~2p) )

i=0

for linenumber in "${scalarLineNums[@]}"
do
sed -i "${linenumber}s/${scalarValuesOriginal[$i]}/${scalarValuesNew[$i]}/" Layer_Rough.Y3D
i=$((i+1))
done
```

The error I receive when trying to run the script is

> sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unknown command: `
>   '

The for loop is an attempt to perform a substitution on a per line basis, i.e., sed 'line#s/oldvalue/newvalue/'. A few of the elements contain '+' and '-' characters as some of the values are stored in scientific notation, but do not contain any slashes or whitespace.

Comment: `set -x` is your friend -- it'll give you the **actual** `sed` command being run.

Comment: ...without that information, there's not enough here to be answerable, as your code can't actually be run. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- in an ideal world, this question would include working [er, failing-as-described] sample values for the arrays, or just not have any arrays at all and hardcode a specific `sed` command that reproduced your problem. And, in an ideal world, it wouldn't depend on `*.Y3D` either -- if your sample data modified, say, line 2, then you could just provide a 3-line heredoc on `sed`'s stdin.

Comment: you have linenumber already why do you need another i?

Comment: The substitution is being performed on a large file (Layer_Rough.Y3D), but the new variables come in a much smaller input file. I'm using the i to cycle through all elements of the input file and linenumber corresponding to the large file (which jumps around from 1  ~1,000,000)  to edit specific lines.

Comment: considering using `-E` with `grep` and `sed` to avoid having to escape all the chars to get an ERE in an BRE.  e.g. `grep -E '(foo|bar)'`.

Comment: Reduce this to a **minimal** example (i.e. a [mcve]) and you'll probably figure out the issue yourself just by doing that.